# Can an Android phone score a neural network in real time?

Tags: android, performance, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a (previously trained) neural network with 1200 pixels (inputs), 20 hidden nodes in a single hidden layer, and one output node.  I believe a new prediction will require (1200*20 multiplications) + (1200*20 sums) + (20 sigmoids) + (20*1 multiplications) + (20*1 sums) + (1 sigmoid) = around 48040 floating point operations + 21 sigmoids, and I need that processing to complete in a fraction of a second on an Android phone.  For simplicity, the pixel information can be pulled directly from a text file with 1200 comma separated values per row.

Is this possible?  And how can I calculate an estimate of the runtime given the processor speed of my phone and the number of operations?  I will be using a Moto X Android phone.

Answer (score 3):

According to the benchmarks at http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/534532 the MotoX can easily deliver over 500 Mflops which is about 1000 times more processing power than you need to run inference on your network 10 times per second. I would be concerned about battery life however.

As a side note, converting the input values from text to floating point is going to be expensive cpu wise, so I'd try to keep them stored as floats if possible.